# I am getting "invalid opcode: INVALID" as error when i try to return an array of structures

Tags: solidity, arrays, brownie, opcode

I am getting error as *ValueError: invalid opcode: INVALID*. Is it because of use of memory and storage keyword in the function or is it because i can't return an array.

**My Solidity Code:-**

```
struct MarketItem {
        uint256 itemId;
        address nftContract;
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 price;
        bool sold;
    }
function getAll() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint256 myCount = 2;
        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](myCount); // here i have memory
        for (uint256 i = 0; i <= myCount; i++) {
            MarketItem storage currentItem = idMarketItem[i]; 
            items[i] = currentItem; // here am storing storage variable to memory
        }
        return items;
    }
```

**My brownie code:-**

```
nftMarket=NFTMarket[-1]
txn3=nftMarket.getAll({'from':account,})
    print(txn3)
```

Comment: nftMarket.getAll({'from':account,}), you're passing account variable, but getAll() function hasn't parameters.